# Xaml WPF MVVM NameSpace & New Project Folder, InitializeComponent(); StartupUri=

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, namespaces

I create some folder and organise my files to keep the MVVM Pattern clean. Model Folder, View Folder and ViewModel Folder.

It creates namespace problems, on many levels.

First the InitializeComponent();

- does not exist in the current context

Second the StartupUri=

- Can't find the ressources

I could find some answers but none were complete.
From the basic situation:

1. I create a new project WPF c# (Lets Name it PROJECT)
2. I create 3 new folder.
3. I move the MainView to the View folder.

What should be in PROJECT\app.xaml ?

- x:Class=""
- StartupUri=""

What should be in PROJECT\View\MainWindow.xaml ?

- x:Class=""

What should be in PROJECT\View\MainWindow.xaml\MainWindow.cs ?

- namespace

What about the PROJECT\ViewModel\FooViewModel.cs ?

What about the PROJECT\Model\FooModel.cs ?

And why ?

So furthe similar question could be completely anwsered. Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't move default files (MainWindow.xaml and App.xaml). Even though it's possible, it's generaly not recommanded as it gives more problems that it gives advantages...

Answer (score 5):

The App.xaml is the starting point of your application. 
x:Class should always define the full namespace of the actual class. so in your example, for the App.xaml is like below:

```
 x:Class="PROJECT.App"
 StartupUri="Viewmodel/MainWindow.xaml"
```

Startup uri defines a relative path to the desired first page. In your case would be *Viewmodel/MainWindow.xaml*.

If you move files from a location to another, you should check the namespace and adjust it accordingly. For your MainWindow would be like here:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace PROJECT.Viewmodel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

- XAML

> ```
> <Window x:Class="PROJECT.Viewmodel.MainWindow"
>         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
>         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
>         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PROJECT"
>         mc:Ignorable="d"
>         Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
>     <Grid>
>
>     </Grid>
> </Window>
> ```

Keep in mind to set both the code behind (.cs) and the xaml file to point the same namespace. Wish you good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, by the way the MainWindow is in the View folder but I get the point

Comment: yes, you are right, is my mistake with the viemodel, but I am glad you work it out

Comment: As an extra bit of information, you aren't limited to `StartupUri` pointing to a `Window`, you can also use `Startup` (instead of `StartupUri`) that points to an event with a handler in `app.xaml`.  I find this startup sequence to be far more useful for MVVM than starting a `Window` directly.  It gives you a chance to run code, set up IOC, and do other initialization steps that don't really fit well in a `Window`'s code-behind or viewmodel.